# Using a WindowsIdentity as a WCF ClientCredential

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm calling a WCF service from a Windows service, and I'd like to authenticate the client through the Windows user that the service is running as.

For various reasons (streaming/SSL, mainly) I have to use anonymous authentication for transport credentials. Is there any way to send my WindowsIdentity through the message, the same way you would normally send ClientCredentials.Username.Username or ClientCredentials.Username.Password?

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;    
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;            
binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;      

ServerContractClient serverConnection = new ServerContractClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(url));

string username = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
serverConnection.ClientCredentials = ???
```